# Does the content type header in RabbitMQ have any special meaning?

Tags: content-type, rabbitmq, amqp

Does the content type header in RabbitMQ have any special meaning, or is it only a standardized way for my producers and consumers to signal what kind of data they are sending? In other words: will messages with certain content types get any special treatment, or is it just bytes, either way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

RabbitMQ doesn't use the content-type header internally at all. It's for producers and consumers to signal message types, as you guessed.